# Angular 6 http: How to send mail with mailgun API using angular 6

Tags: angular, api, mailgun

I want to send mail to user from angular 6 front-end. I want to use mailgun api to do this. Here is an example with curl that is working find and I want to "translate" this into angular 6 http:

```
curl -s --user 
'api:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'  
https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.og/messages  
-F from='Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@sandbox5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org>'  
-F to='Big boss <xxxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com>'  
-F subject='Hello mdx'  
-F text='This is cool !'
```

I have tried this :

```
 sendMail(form) {
    this.http
      .post(
        'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.og/messages',

          {
            'from': 'Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@sandbox5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx9.mailgun.org>',
            'to': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com',
            'subject': 'Hello',
            'text': 'This is cool !'
          }

      )
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log('res : ', res);
        },
        err => {
          console.log('err : ', err);
        }
      );
  }
```

When I click on send, I got this error:
[image]

Any idea on how to write this curl into angular ?

Answer (score 2):

Try the following using `FormData` to the create the `multipart/form-data` and using a **Basic** `Authorization` header for the username/password `--user` authentication:

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

// ...

const headers = new HttpHeaders({
  'enctype': 'multipart/form-data',
  'Authorization': `Basic ${btoa('api:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')}`
});

const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('from', 'Mailgun Sandbox <postmaster@sandbox5xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx9.mailgun.org>')
formData.append('to', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com');
formData.append('subject', 'Hello');
formData.append('text', 'This is cool !');

sendMail(form) {
  this.http
    .post(
      'https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandboxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.og/messages',
      formData, 
      { headers }
    ).subscribe(
      res => { console.log('res : ', res); },
      err => { console.log('err : ', err); }
    );
}
```

You may be able to get with not using `enctype` or `Content-Type` request headers.

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your `curl` example in which you use the `-F` flag, mailgun is expecting multipart Post data. Your Angular attempt simply sends the data as a JSON object, which is not the same. Instead create a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object, add your data in there, then POST your FormData object.